# PGFPlots viridis colormap

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a PGFPlots `surf` using the colormap viridis in a similar fashion as some examples of the PGFPlots package manual. I will get the error

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/colormap/viridis' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \end{axis}

when using the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}                       % don't show the page number

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps} 
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps} 
\usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.colormaps] 

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/viridis , hide axis]
        \addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,samples=20,domain=-1:0,y domain=0:2*pi]
        ({-2*x * cos(deg(y))},
        {-2*x* sin(deg(y))},
        -x^2+100);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

I also tried `colormap name=viridis`, but still no cigar. Any ideas

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! I suspect that you just need to load a pgf library. It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.  In particular, here it would be helpful to know exactly what packages you are using. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated the code.

Comment: Looks like this colormap is an addon to the latest version of pgfplots. Are your Latex packages up to date?

Comment: As Jens PLoz mentioned the package required updating. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colormap 'viridis' is an addon to the latest version of pgfplots. After updating my Latex packages it worked for me.

[image]